# Pie Chart without "Time" in Apache Superset

Tags: dashboard, apache-superset

Creating a Pie Chart within Apache Superset currently requires a "Time" column, is it possible to plot data without this need for a datetime field?

When plotting something like the result of a poll (e.g. people's favourite food, categories vs count), there is no concept of a datetime field.

Comment: I answered the question, but separately I suggest filing a new Discussion on the Apache Superset Github suggesting an improvement here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a pie chart without this field (at least in 2.0.0 or higher).

It's a little confusing because if your dataset has a datetime field, it will automatically get added to the Time field and you will be unable to remove it.  But it shouldn't affect the chart, and if you try to use a dataset without a datetime field, you can still create pie charts.

In short, I think you can just ignore that field.